# AngularJS function and $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function defined in my controller like this:

```
var getTransactions = function(transactionType, partnerId) {
        return loadTexts.getTransactionTexts(transactionType, partnerId).then(function (res) {
            $scope.loadedTexts = res.data.Transactions;
        });
    };
```

Another $scope function is calling it. Now, when I put console.log for `res.data.Transactions`, everything is logged as it has to be, but when I want to assign that data to $scope variable, it simply doesn't work. (After `load` function, `$scope.loadedTexts` is empty however)

```
$scope.load = function() {
        getTransactions($scope.TransactionTypeId, $scope.selectedPartner.Id);
    };
```

Any help?

CODE:

```
 app.controller("textsController", function ($scope, $http, autoComplete, loadTexts) {

        $scope.selectedPartner = { "Name": "", "Id": null };
        $scope.loadedTexts = [];

        .. other functions are here ...

        var getTransactions = function(transactionType, partnerId) {
            return loadTexts.getTransactionTexts(transactionType, partnerId);
        };

        $scope.load = function () {
            getTransactions($scope.transactionType, $scope.selectedPartner.Id).then(function(res) {
                $scope.loadedTexts = res.data.Transactions;
            });
        };

    });
```

Comment: Try returning a promise from `getTransactions`, and execute the callback and do the assignment in `load`.

Comment: How to return promise?

Comment: `getTransactionTexts` returns a promise already, then execute the `then` callback inside `load`, and do the scope assignment there.

Comment: It doesn't work, same thing again

Comment: you are writing a promise for getting the data.Actually, data is not available outside of the promise.So, include your functionality inside the promise

Comment: the structure of your code seems right, could you provide more code, maybe somewhere else you're changing $scope.loadedTexts, also how and when you check $scope.loadedTexts, because it will be loaded with delay.

Comment: I copied more code. I just put <p ng-repeat="text in loadedTexts">...

Comment: could you reproduce your problem in this plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/1Co5JgUEdamcu1LurPfw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are showing everything looks fine to me. Note however, that you are storing a reference to Transactions within loadedTexts. Maybe the "Transactions" object res.Data.Transactions is somehow cleared elsewhere.
You could try to copy the object instead of assigning a reference (use e.g. angular.copy) to test if this is the cause.